# Regex for extracting functions from C++ code

Tags: c++, regex, function, visual-studio-2012

I have sample C++ code (http://pastebin.com/6q7zs7tc) from which I have to extract functions names as well as the number of parameters that a function requires. So far I have written this regex, but it's not working perfectly for me.

```
(?![a-z])[^\:,>,\.]([a-z,A-Z]+[_]*[a-z,A-Z]*)+[(]
```

Comment: First, you should say what you expect it to do and what it actually does that is not perfect. Second, you probably need some sort of parser a bit more powerful than regex. C++ is not a regular language (and people will argue all day about whether it is context free - please don't go there).

Comment: No regex can do this job perfectly. Doing this (even close to) truly correctly is a seriously non-trivial task, but if you *really* need to do it, you can use something like CLang (but even just making use of CLang isn't trivial).

Comment: You can't do this with a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't parse C++ reliably with regex.

In fact, you can't parse it with weak parsing technology (See [Why can't C++ be parsed with a LR(1) parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-cant-c-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/1004737#1004737)).  If you expect to get extract this information reliably from source files, you will need a time-tested C++ parser; see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28825789/120163

If you don't care that your extraction process is flaky, then you can use a regex and maybe some additional hackery.  Your key problem for heuristic extraction is matching various kinds of brackets, e.g., [...],  < ... > (which won't quite work for shift operators) and { ... }.   Bracket matching requires you to keep a stack of seen brackets.   And bracket matching may fail in the presence of macros and preprocessor conditionals.