# Check if C++ headers are self contained

Tags: c++, cmake, include, header-files, self-contained

I want to create a solution to control if header inclusions are done properly. Imagine a following scenario:

```
myProject
    | _____ foo.cpp
    | _____ foo_public.h
    | _____ bar.cpp
    | _____ bar_public.h
    | _____ baz.cpp
    | _____ baz.h
```

inside foo_public.h stands following `#include "bar_public.h"`

When someone edits the bar_public.h accidentally with `#include "baz.h"` that solution should catch this since the file does not end with **"*_public.h"** and give and error in build. Such inclusion error can occur in every header file that ends with _public. For the rest this rule is not important.

Some guarantees in the project:

- Each header file is a C++ header file, cmake is used in the project
- All inclusions are done with `#include` directives inside files.
- All files needs to be checked complies a certain file name pattern ("*_public.h")
- All files are inside myProject folder. (The depth could change but that depth is also reflected in inclusion statement eg. myProject/newFile/new_intface_public.h -> included as
  `#include "myProject/newFile/new_intface_public.h"`

I don't know which direction should I go, I thought I can use CMake functions for this purpose but I am new to CMake, I don't know where to start. Some alternatives in my mind:

1. Get all the include statements from the C++ headers matching the pattern and parse them: I read parsing C++ header was not a straightforward action from [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825628/c-header-file-parsing)
2. In CMake create a new target/C++ file that includes all the files matching the pattern (included files are copied in a separate redundant place), compile that target and there is no error: Mainly I am interested in this solution but I don't know where I should start.

Any ideas, comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually need to differentiate between public/private headers located in the same directory? The usual approach to that in CMake projects is to have them in separate directories (usually sth like `lib/include/lib/public_header.h` , and `lib/src/private_header.h`) and control the inclusion via `target_include_directories` (hint use `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE` to differentiate).

Comment: *"Each header file is a cpp file"* -- This doesn't look right. The `.cpp` files are your source files, and your header files are the `.h` files. I'm going to edit the question assuming you meant C++ (not to be confused with `cpp`, a C preprocessor).

Comment: @JaMiT In principle every cpp file can include any kind of header. The solution should catch cases wheater "*_public.h" headers contain non "*_public.h" header inclusions.

Comment: @paler123 no this is not the case of course public and private headers are separated in the project, this is just an example scenario

Comment: The proper policy is to keep this header included at top of respective source file (just after precompiled headers). Then if header is not self contain this source file compilation will fail. Note that clang format has proper option to sort includes of header files in such way.

Comment: https://include-what-you-use.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CMake code should do the job.

```cmake
# Get a list of '*_public.h' files
file(
  GLOB_RECURSE _public_files
  LIST_DIRECTORIES false
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*_public.h)

# Generate a project in '/public_if_test/' in the build folder and
# for every header file:
#  * generate a source file which includes only the header file
#  * copy the header file
set(_gen_source_files "")
foreach(header_file ${_public_files})
  get_filename_component(_name ${header_file} NAME_WLE)
  file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/public_if_test/${_name}.cpp"
       "#include \"${header_file}\"")
  file(COPY "${header_file}"
       DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/public_if_test/")
  list(APPEND _gen_source_files
       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/public_if_test/${_name}.cpp")
endforeach()

# Create a build target to check if the '*_public.h' files are self contained
add_library(test_public_interface MODULE ${_gen_source_files})
```

An build error is generated, if a header file is not fully self contained.